# How to make regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone advise me on how to check the number is in the following format using regular expression in java script

```
12-1234567-123
```

Thanks

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ provides a good introduction to regular expressions. I suggest  you have a look at it and learn at least the basics (which is all that is needed here).

Comment: What format do you have to check for? `dd-ddddddd-ddd` ? Where `d = number`

Answer (score 6):

Try the following:

```
/^[\d]{2}-[\d]{7}-[\d]{3}$/
```

This roughly equates to

```
^ = start of string
[/d] = any number (0-9)
{n} = exactly n times
$ = end of string
```

Which is useable like so:

```
var string = '12-1234567-123';
var regex = /^[\d]{2}-[\d]{7}-[\d]{3}$/;
if (regex.test(string)) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

one possible regex for that:

```
var format = /^\d{2}-\d{7}-\d{3}$/
```

and to test:

```
if( format.test( number ) ){
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
/^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{7}-[0-9]{3}$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your pattern is dd-ddddddd-ddd (i.e., the actual numbers in your example aren't part of the pattern):

```
var num = "12-1234567-123";

if (/^\d{2}-\d{7}-\d{3}$/.test(num)) {
    alert("Number is valid");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

\d{2}-\d{7}-\d{3} to match your case exactly as you quoted.

If you need to specify the numerals (ie max value of 7) replace \d{2} with [0-7]{2} etc.

A great regexp tester : [RegExp example](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html)

Answer (score 0):

hyphens should be escaped into the regexp so try this

```
/\d{2}\-\d{7}\-\d{3}/
```

Comment: hyphens only need to be escaped in ranges

Comment: isn't it only when they are in character classes?

Comment: yes but since I often work with complex regulars expressions I think it's a good practice always escape them especially on nested ranges  patterns, just for a matter of clarity and readability - Not really this case anyway

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is a "nested range"?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very loose RegEx.:

```
/\d{2}-\d{7}-\d{3}/.test("12-1234567-123")
```

You should give more details about edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

use this regex string:

```
\d{2}-\d{7}-\d{3}
```

and the way to use regex match in javascript:

```
var isValid = /\d{2}-\d{7}-\d{3}/.test(input)
```